# why i have an error when i use on update cascade?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to add a constraint to the foreign key + on update cascade, but it shows an error, why?

```
SQL> alter table affaire_cassation
   2  add constraint key_fk_num_p foreign key(num_aff_a) references 
    affaire_appel(num_aff)
    3  on update cascade;
```

on update cascade
   *
ERREUR Ó la ligne 3 :
ORA-00905: mot-clÚ absent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in oracle.

you may want to look at `deferrable constraints` which defers the foreign key check until commit, update the parent, update the child and then commit.

```
ALTER TABLE affaire_cassation
ADD CONSTRAINT key_fk_num_p 
FOREIGN KEY(num_aff_a) 
REFERENCES affaire_appel(num_aff)
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

You may also look for `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE` where you can defer the constraints on demand when you need it.

---

use with  `ALTER SESSION SET CONSTRAINTS = DEFERRED;`

Comment: hmmm , first time in oracle :p thx for your help

Comment: but I still when I update primary key in affaire_appel I still get an error because it's not update in affaire_cassation

Comment: check my update please

Comment: yes yes sry thx